# Switching data types based on system?

Tags: types, architecture, rust, 32bit-64bit

I have a project where I need to read some bytes from disk. If the system is a 64 bit system, this will read a double word to get the correct amount of bytes. If it is a 32 bit system it will read a single word.

I'd like to have one type that can represent either of these options. call it `SystemWord`.

I'm unsure of the best way to handle this in a way that will allow me to have something like

```
let test: SystemWord = 0x01;
```

and it will know immediately whether to choose u64 or u32.

Can anyone provide any guidance on the best way to do this? I'm still fairly new to Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean `usize`, as [explained in the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html#variable-sized-types)?

That's the solution to what you appear to *actually* want.  The solution to what you *asked* is [conditional compilation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html), like so:

```rust
#[cfg(target_pointer_width="32")]
type SystemWord = u32;

#[cfg(target_pointer_width="64")]
type SystemWord = u64;
```

But don't do that when you can just use `usize`.  In fact, don't do it unless you *absolutely* have to, since this will often lead to you having two or more code paths in your code: one that's well tested, and the other which is often not tested *at all*.

Comment: wow nice! usize, thats interesting. Thank you! If I just set it to usize I can let Rust handle it.